# How to select a column in a dataframe by its number instead of its name

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I'd like to select a Column in a Spark dataframe by its number instead of it's name. Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689460/select-specific-columns-from-spark-dataframe/51708946#51708946

Comment: Import spark implicits first which acts as a helper class for usage of $-notation to access the columns using the positional indexes

`import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val child3_DF  = parentDF.select("_c0","_c1","_c2","_c8","_c9").show()`

Comment: I've tried that before posting, but it doesn't work for me. It looks for the column named "_c0".           Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`_c0`' given input columns: [meterid, qewr, nevents, fasf, adfet];;
'Project ['_c0, '_c1]
+- Relation[meterid#105,nevents#106,adfet#107,qewr#108,fasf#109] JDBCRelation(meterproperties) [numPartitions=1]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to write your own method for this you can do:

```
package utils

object Extensions {
    implicit class DataFrameExtensions(df: DataFrame) {
        def selecti(indices: Int*) = {
            val cols = df.columns
            df.select(indices.map(cols(_)):_*)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can import and use this method as:

```
import utils.Extensions._

df.selecti(1,2,3)
```