# Spark Scala: functional difference in notation using $?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a functional difference between the following two expressions? The result looks the same to me but curious if there's an unknown unknown. What does the `$` symbol indicate/how is it read?

```scala
df1.orderBy($"reasonCode".asc).show(10, false)
    
df1.orderBy(asc("reasonCode")).show(10, false)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those two statements are equivalent and will lead to the identical result.

The `$` notation is special for Scala Spark and is referring to an implicit `StringToColumn` method which interprets the subsequent string "reasonCode" as a `Column`

```scala
implicit class StringToColumn(val sc: StringContext) {
  def $(args: Any*): ColumnName = {
    new ColumnName(sc.s(args: _*))
  }
}
```

In Scala Spark you have many ways to select a column. I have written down a full list of syntax varieties in another answer on [select specific columns from spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689460/select-specific-columns-from-spark-dataframe/65000094#65000094).

Using different notations do not have any impact on the performance as they all get translated to the same set of RDD instructions through Spark's Catalyst optimizer.

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there any difference in compute time? For example, some people debate the difference between `SELECT(1)` vs. `SELECT(*)` for SQL. F

Comment: As far as I am aware it is all syntactic sugar and in the end it gets translated/compiled to the same RDD instruction by the Catalyst optimizer of Spark.