# spark Dataframe clarification on select

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have created one dataframe ordersDF.Below is the schema.

```
root
 |-- order_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- order_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- order_customer_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- order_status: string (nullable = true)
```

In some places we are using 'order_id', order_id,ordersDF.order_id.It is really confusing when to use which one.
For example.

```
1)ordersDF.select(order_id).show() -- NameError: name 'order_id' is not defined
 ordersDF.where('order_id==9').show() --No error here
 
 2)ordersDF.select('order_id').show() --No error here
 
 3)ordersDF.select(ordersDF.order_id).show()--No error here
 
 4)ordersDF.where('ordersDF.order_id==9').show() --AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`ordersDF.order_id`' given input columns: [order_customer_id, order_date, order_id, order_status]; line 1 pos 0;
```

Comment: Clarify what is your exact problem. Show your efforts and errors. Look at the best way of posting a question on SO

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689460/select-specific-columns-from-spark-dataframe/65000094#65000094) might help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are confused while passing a column.
Use `DF.ColumnName` without any `'` or pass column name under single quotes like `'order_id'`.  You can use any of these ways to pass the column.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)],['id','value'])
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df.withColumn("value_desc",when('value' == 1, 'one').when(df.value == 2, 'two').otherwise('other')).show()

Comment: I got error as TypeError: condition should be a Column.As you mentioned earlier I am using column 'Value' in single quatoes

Comment: My bad use double quotes

Comment: I am a beginner.could u please elabarote it. as u mentioned earlier I used 'value' column in single quatoes.Now tried double quatoes as well but still not working df.withColumn("value_desc",when("value" == 1, 'one').when(df.value == 2, 'two').otherwise('other')).show()

Comment: You can also try col method like first import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.* and then use col("column name")

Answer (score 0):

The select and where functions either take a string or column object as input. You mix them up.

1a) You want to access a column which is the name of the variable `order_id` in python. However you don't have a variable defined. This is passing a string.
1b) This is spark SQL, column `order_id` should be `9`. This translates to `select * from ordersDF where order_id=9`. This is passing a string.
2) Spark sql for selecting a column, similar to 1a. Translates to `select order_id from ordersDF`. This is passing a string.
3) Here you pass a column object, by `DF.column`
4) Here you pass a string, that is just not a column name. Spark can actually have `.` in column names (but not if you save it to hive). So it's looking for a column that does not exist. Note that if you want to use a tablename anyway you can use aliases. `ordersDF.alias("ordersDF").select("ordersDF.orderId")` works.